# how ro correctly import font-face in svg file using nestjs and angular

Tags: html, angular, svg, backend, nestjs

i have a problem with my svg file. I'm trying to bind a font-family in my svg file but i get an error
here my svg in backend:

```
<svg

   width="75mm"
   height="80mm"
   viewBox="0 0 75 80"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8">
     <defs>
   <style type="text/css">
      @font-face{
              font-family: fam;
               src: url('../assets/Heebo-Regular.ttf');
      }
   </style>
   </defs>

.
.
.
</svg>
```

And there my html in frontend

```
 <div>
  <object class="print" [data]="safeUri" type="image/svg+xml" size="A4" style="width: 500px; height: 600px;">
  </object><br>
  </div>
```

in **safeUri** i' m making the get request to my svg but i get this error in frontend:
**GET http://localhost:3000/test/assets/Heebo-Regular.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**
Do maybe someone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the path to the following:

from `src: url('../assets/Heebo-Regular.ttf');`

to `src: url('assets/Heebo-Regular.ttf');`

```
<svg

   width="75mm"
   height="80mm"
   viewBox="0 0 75 80"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8">
     <defs>
   <style type="text/css">
      @font-face{
              font-family: fam;
               src: url('assets/Heebo-Regular.ttf');
      }
   </style>
   </defs>

.
.
.
</svg>
```

Comment: @ Sef thank for your answer.... but the **...** just mean thast assest is not in the Folder than my svg-file